# Add single push notification to single device

Tags: c#, ios, azure, apple-push-notifications

I'm creating an ios application using swift for the client and C# for the server. I currently have a web app hosted in azure that communicate with the client via web api. Now I need to employ push notifications

1. I'm looking at Azure tutorials as my push notification provider, but it seems that it only cares about sending mass broadcasting. My need is to send custom notifications per user/device for specific notification such as "someone liked your profile" or "someone wants to connect with you" or that sort of 1-1 notifications. But look at azure example [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-ios-get-started-push/) at the section: Update server project to send push notifications (.Net) #3, there is no indication of sending a message to only one device, but rather to any device who connect to the specific hub. 
   So, I think the azure tutorials are not what I am looking for.
2. look at this lean [code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28086819/1019042): He doesn't seem to be relying on any server like azure to send his notification. He is not using a hub either. He is just sending everything from a TcpClient and his notification is direct at 1 device like need it (note the deviceID he is receiving). But I've read that you must use an APNS provider all the time, so, where is his?

so, do I have to use Azure (if I want to stick to MS) to do 1-1 push notification? Does it support that? Any good tutorial about that? Or I don't need it and just simple block of C# is enough? 
(I would try the code in option #2 out, but I have to setup the certificate and report back before being allocated more time)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after much investigation and trials, I found out that I don't have to rely on azure, its push notification or anything like that. I can do the entire thing by executing C# code like #2. 
All I had to do is setup the .p12 certificate and give it a password. Bring it over from Mac to my pc and executed the C# code and was able to receive notifications on my phone.